# Apache running MongoDB and PHP

Tags: apache, mongodb, database-connection

I'm using `XAMPP` in my `Mac OSX`. I've installed `mongodb` and copied the `.so` file into `xampp` plugins folder. My `phpinfo()` of the page shows that `MongoDB` section which is installed.

After i start `Apache of XAMPP` server, when i code

```
m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->mydatabase;
$collection = $db->myCollection;
```

Its saying some `Fatal Error`.

If i run `mongod` command in `Terminal` window, its working. Then what is the use of installing `mongodb` in `XAMPP` server. My Questions are

1. Why its working like that..?
2. Is there any way to start `mongod` when we start `Apache` server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why its working like that..?

Installing the PHP driver and the MongoDB server are two completely different things.

This is very basic driver stuff; you require a library or communication layer that can route your PHP programming to the MongoDB server (basically).

> Is there any way to start mongod when we start Apache server.

You could make an `sh` script that looks like:

```
/etc/init.d/xammp_service_dunno_what_it_is_called start
/etc/init.d/mongodb start
```

Then you could just attach to the startup, or even better you can just attach both services (XAMPP and MongoDB) to the startup of your computer.

However, as far as I know, there is no way to create a sort of trigger mechanism that will load up MongoDB when the OS detects that you have started running Apache.

Comment: Thanks @Sammaye. One more doubt, My plan is to host my website in my home server. That time, do i've to run both Apache and MongoDB server to run my PHP application.

Comment: @arthan.v Yes, they will need to be running either on separate machines with PHP talking to an external MongoDB or internally on the same machine in your bedroom